# Parallel recursion in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, concurrency

I am trying to parallelize recursive calls of sudoku solver from [25 lines Sudoku solver in Scala](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/25-lines-Sudoku-solver-in-Scala-td1987506.html). I've changed their `Fold` into `reduce`

```
def reduce(f: (Int, Int) => Int, accu: Int, l: Int, u: Int): Int = {
  accu + (l until u).toArray.reduce(f(accu, _) + f(accu, _))
}
```

which if run sequentially works fine, but when I change it into

```
  accu + (l until u).toArray.par.reduce(f(accu, _) + f(accu, _))
```

the recursion reaches the bottom much more often and generates false solutions. I thought, that it will execute the bottom level recursion and work it's way up, but doesn't seem to do so.

I've also tried futures

```
def parForFut2(f: (Int, Int) => Int, accu: Int, l: Int, u: Int): Int = {
  var sum: Int = accu
  val vals = l until u
  vals.foreach(t => scala.actors.Futures.future(sum + f(accu, t)))
  sum
}
```

which appears to have the same problem as the `par.reduce`. I would appreciate any comment. The whole code is here:

```
object SudokuSolver extends App {
// The board is represented by an array of string 
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./puzzle")
val lines = (source.getLines).toArray
var m: Array[Array[Char]] = for (
  str <- lines;
  line: Array[Char] = str.toArray
) yield line
source.close()

// For printing m
def print = {
  Console.println("");
  refArrayOps(m) map (carr => Console.println(new String(carr)))
}

// The test for validity of n on position x,y
def invalid(i: Int, x: Int, y: Int, n: Char): Boolean =
  i < 9 && (m(y)(i) == n || m(i)(x) == n ||
  m(y / 3 * 3 + i / 3)(x / 3 * 3 + i % 3) == n || invalid(i + 1, x, y, n))

// Looping over a half-closed range of consecutive Integers [l..u) 
// is factored out Into a higher-order function
def parReduce(f: (Int, Int) => Int, accu: Int, l: Int, u: Int): Int = {
  accu + (l until u).toArray.par.reduce(f(accu, _) + f(accu, _))
}

// The search function examines each position on the board in turn, 
// trying the numbers 1..9 in each unfilled position 
// The function is itself a higher-order fold, accumulating the value 
// accu by applying the given function f to it whenever a solution m 
// is found 
def search(x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int) => Int, accu: Int): Int = Pair(x, y) match {
  case Pair(9, y) => search(0, y + 1, f, accu) // next row 
  case Pair(0, 9) => f(accu) // found a solution - print it and continue
  case Pair(x, y) => if (m(y)(x) != '0') search(x + 1, y, f, accu) else
    parForFut1((accu: Int, n: Int) =>
      if (invalid(0, x, y, (n + 48).asInstanceOf[Char])) accu else {
        m(y)(x) = (n + 48).asInstanceOf[Char];
        val newaccu = search(x + 1, y, f, accu);
        m(y)(x) = '0';
        newaccu
      }, accu, 1, 10)
}

// The main part of the program uses the search function to accumulate 
// the total number of solutions 
Console.println("\n" + search(0, 0, i => { print; i + 1 }, 0) + " solution(s)")
}
```

Comment: don't use mutable data structures / vars; start by making your methods pure functions and then work on parallel execution

Comment: Thanks, it did help in the end. It makes you understand what variables (values) you are changing whenb you don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Andreas comment I changed the `m: Array[Array[Char]]` into `m: List[List[Char]]` which prevents any unnecessary and unwanted changes to it. The final looping method is

```
    def reduc(f: (Int, Int) => Int, 
                  accu: Int, l: Int, u: Int, m1: List[List[Char]]):Int =
    accu + (l until u).toArray.par.reduce(f(accu, _) + f(accu, _))
```

and I had to pass m as an argument to each used function, so every one of them had its own instance of it. The whole code:

```
    object SudokuSolver extends App{
      // The board is represented by an Array of strings (Arrays of Chars),
      val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./puzzle")

      val lines = source.getLines.toList             
      val m: List[List[Char]] = for (
        str <- lines;
        line: List[Char] = str.toList
      ) yield line 
      source.close()

      // For prInting m
      def printSud(m: List[List[Char]]) = {
        Console.println("")
        m map (println)
      }                                               

      Console.println("\nINPUT:")                     
      printSud(m)  

      def invalid(i:Int, x:Int, y:Int, n:Char,m1: List[List[Char]]): Boolean =
        i < 9 && (m1(y)(i) == n || m1(i)(x) == n ||
          m1(y / 3 * 3 + i / 3)(x / 3 * 3 + i % 3) == n ||
          invalid(i + 1, x, y, n, m1))

      def reduc(f: (Int, Int) => Int, accu: Int, l: Int, u: Int, 
                m1: List[List[Char]]): Int =
        accu + (l until u).toArray.par.reduce(f(accu, _) + f(accu, _))

      def search(x: Int, y: Int, accu: Int, m1: List[List[Char]]): Int = 
        Pair(x, y) match {
          case Pair(9, y) => search(0, y + 1, accu, m1) // next row
          case Pair(0, 9) => { printSud(m1); accu + 1 } // found a solution
          case Pair(x, y) =>
            if (m1(y)(x) != '0')
              search(x + 1, y, accu, m1) // place is filled, we skip it.
            else // box is not filled, we try all n in {1,...,9}
              reduc((accu: Int, n: Int) => {
                if (invalid(0, x, y, (n + 48).asInstanceOf[Char], m1))
                  accu
                else { // n fits here
                  val line = List(m1(y).patch(x, Seq((n + 48).asInstanceOf[Char]), 1))
                  val m2 = m1.patch(y, line, 1)
                  val newaccu = search(x + 1, y, accu, m2);
                  val m3 = m1.patch(y, m1(y).patch(x, Seq(0), 1), 1)
                  newaccu
                }
            }, accu, 1, 10, m1)
      }                                               

      Console.println("\n" + search(0, 0, 0, m) + " solution(s)")

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, recursion is inherently sequential (i.e. not parallelizable).

I'd reason it like this: recursion means (put simply) 'call myself'. A function call always happens within one and exactly one thread.

If you are telling the function to call itself, then you are staying in that thread - you're not dividing the work (i.e. making it parallel).

Recursion and parallelism are related though, but not at the function-call level. They are related in the sense that *tasks* can be recursively decomposed into smaller parts, that can be performed in parallel.

Comment: by that logic, you could never parallelize e.g. a fold or a merge sort - but you can

Comment: Folds are not recursive function calls. Folds can be implemented in terms of recursion, but that is a different matter. Feel free to provide a concrete counterexample in which explicit recursion is parallelized.

Comment: So now we've arrived at the realization that not all types of recursion are the same, which is already a good bit less general than your initial statement.

Comment: I don't think so - the concepts of recursion and reduction are orthogonal. There's a whole framework built on top of that idea: http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html

Comment: While that is true, the original issue was recursion and parallelism, and I was saying that a fold can be parallelized while still being recursive. Same goes for a merge sort (which is a very different type of recursion): it can be parallelized and stay recursive.

Comment: Recursive calls can happen inside a `Future` block or inside some callback which will be executed on a different thread.